# Passing a variable to a Rails SLIM view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

```
Rails 5
SLIM
Bootstrap 4
```

In one of my views, I have something like this:

```
- if sales > 2000
  button.btn-primary type="button"
- if sales.between?(1000, 2000)
  button.btn-warning type="button"
- if sales < 1000
  button.btn-danger type="button"
```

What I would like to do, is resolve this in the Helper, and pass a variable to the view, as the type of button to use. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

In **HELPER**:

```
def sales_button(sales)
    case
    when sales > 2000
      "btn-primary"
    when sales.between?(1000, 2000)
      "btn-warning"
    when sales < 1000
      "btn-danger"
    end
end
```

In **VIEW**:

```
button *{class: sales_button(sales) } type="button"
```